# The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly when iis have a subroot

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Please find my client code

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
string serverNameOne= "http://servername/wespapi/api/task/GetGanttTasks";
string ServerName= "http://servername/api/task/GetGanttTasks";
var response = client.PostAsync(durl1,content).Result;
return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is my client code to call web api. All other methods are working fine with serverNameOne  address. only here i have a problem. when i use ServerName without the sub root it works fine.

Exception details :

```
 InnerException {"Error while copying content to a stream."} System.Exception {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException}
```

Inner Exception

```
InnerException {"The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
```

Any luck ?

Thanks

Sarath

Comment: Are you able to debug into the server side (i.e. is your web api endpoint executing)?

Comment: I guess you should review your routing.. it's weird enough that two URLs could point to the same controller :-)

Comment: Two url is not pointing to same controller. It is two deployment in the same sever just to test.  Yes Both the end point is working as expected when i test with postman